# Check if invited user has accepted B2B invite

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I'm automating Azure B2B Invitation process. At this stage I need to know if invited user has accepted invite or not.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any programmatic way to do this at the moment as far as I can tell.

The attribute that tells you the the status is named `source` and can be read through the UI:

[image: Azure AD - Profile]

but is not included in the PowerShell cmdlet output for getting a user, nor in the Azure AD Graph API.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-user-properties) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed some way of quickly determining the list of users who hadn't accepted these invitations.  I realize the question is tagged with C#, but I ended up using PowerShell to accomplish this goal.

There exists a PowerShell module for [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0), which has a Cmdlet named [`Get-AzureADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0), that can give you the information you need.

Install the AzureAD PowerShell module by running the following command:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

After installation, you must import the module to make the Cmdlets available, and then authenticate:

```
Import-Module AzureAd
Connect-AzureAD
```

From here, it's a simple command to pull a list of all the users that *haven't* accepted the invitations:

```
Get-AzureADUser `
| Where-Object { $_.UserType -eq 'Guest' -and $_.UserState -eq 'PendingAcceptance' } `
| Select-Object -Property DisplayName,Mail,UserState,UserStateChangedOn `
| Sort-Object -Property DisplayName `
| Format-Table -AutoSize
```

To see a list of users who have accepted invitations, you can instead use `$_.UserState -eq 'Accepted'` within the `Where-Object` ScriptBlock.